# Image tracker in email does not work via outlook proxy

Tags: php, email, outlook

I am creating a simple email open rate tracker, and I include a tracker to our outgoing email as a 1x1 pixel image:

```
http://myserver.com/tracker.php?&campID=1&email=testEmail%40hotmail.com
```

When I go to this address explicitly, it works fine.

However, when I just open the email normally, our server does not get updated.

I notice that Outlook have changed the image address to:

```
https://bay179.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&canary=DYEtBG9j7A375IRcXrmghGt33mKTW3qtJbfC2khuPdA%3d0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Ftracker.php%3F%26campID%3D1%26email%3DtestEmail%2540hotmail.com
```

How do I get my tracker to load normally?

Comment: are you allowing images to load in outlook?

Comment: I don't have any images, just a tracker, I would assume yes, but I will go do a test.